# Custom UITableViewCell not calling prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I have a custom UITableViewCell, called `EventCell`.

**EventCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EventCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *locationLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *typeLabel;
@end
```

**EventCell.m**

```
#import "EventCell.h"

@implementation EventCell

@synthesize titleLabel, locationLabel, dateLabel, typeLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Here is how I'm setting up my cell.

**EventsMasterViewController.m**

```
- (EventCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Event *myEvent;
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";
    EventCell *cell = (EventCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EventCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[EventCell class]])
        {
            cell = (EventCell *)currentObject;
            break;
         }
    }

    myEvent = [self.myEventsDataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.titleLabel.text = myEvent.name;
    cell.locationLabel.text = myEvent.location;
    cell.typeLabel.text = @"Social";
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

    return cell;
}
```

The cell is being formatted great, it looks exactly as I need it to. But when I click on it, the cell highlights blue and doesn't segue to the next view. I put a breakpoint in my prepareForSegue method and it's not even getting called.

Is there some way to call prepareForSegue manually? If so, where should I do that.

Comment: What about your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: I don't have a method called that, would I need to implement that?

Comment: From what I'm reading, don't we use `prepareForSegue` in lieu of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:nil];


}
```

Comment: note that both didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and prepareForSegue: are methods of UIViewController and not of UITableViewCell

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't *have* to implement `didSelectRow` for this to work - control-dragging from a cell to another view controller should create a segue that works when tapping the cell.

In my case, the problem was that the storyboard editor was creating the segue incorrectly. I had two very similar storyboards, one worked and the other didn't, and looking at the source code (right click on the storyboard file and choose *Open As* -> *Source Code*), I saw this:

```
<segue destination="UWX-rF-KOc" kind="replace" identifier="showStory" trigger="accessoryAction" splitViewControllerTargetIndex="1" id="Gly-La-KIe"/>
```

Note the `trigger` attribute. This suggests to me that the segue will be fired from the accessory action of the cell. You can even see this from the connections inspector of the cell:

[image]

Removing this and replacing the segue by dragging from the "selection" handle above instead of control-dragging from the cell gave me the correct segue.

I'm not sure what it is about this particular cell that makes control-dragging connect to the accessory action instead of the selection action, but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, you need to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` unless you configure a segue in your storyboard to a new `UIViewController`. This allows you to use the `prepareForSegue` function instead of the programmatic call of `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Hope that helps clear it up!

Comment: I don't think `didSelectRowAtIndex` is a function. Please check your answer and correct function name if is incorrect.

Comment: Looks like I missed the path at the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the cell identifier.

So, in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I declared `static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";` and then in storyBoard I added this identifier in here:

[image]

And here you go!