# Master Detail Scene, Detail scene wont load properly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, segue, master-detail

im following this ios tutorial:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingDetailView/CustomizingDetailView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH5-SW3

and im creating a master scene and a detail scene. they are both done as described in the tutorial.

Right now the problem is that when i enter the detail scene, the layout of detail scene is not loaded. instead, a master scene layout with nothing on it is loaded.

So far from what i can see, the problem has to do with transferring the data from master scene to detail scene.

The tutorial does not include this method:

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

without it, the app couldnt go from master scene to detail scene. i think the segue method was suppose to transfer the data and make it go to detail scene, but for some reason it doesnt. so this method was edited to

{

```
    BirdSighting *sightingAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    BirdsDetailViewController *bd= [[BirdsDetailViewController alloc] init];

    bd.sighting = sightingAtIndex;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bd animated:YES];
```

}

and now the app can go from master scene to detail scene, but the detail scene looks like a master scene with nothing on it.

Any help regarding this or the transferring data between the scenes are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem seem to come down to prepareForSegue isnt being called, and just using didselectrowatindexpath isnt transferring the data correctly.

so you can fix it by looking at this answer here: 
[Custom UITableViewCell not calling prepareForSegue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915789/custom-uitableviewcell-not-calling-prepareforsegue)

Seems like when user touch a cell, didSelectRowAtIndex is called, but prepareForSegue isnt. So you need to manually call performSegue for prepareForSegue to work? this is my interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the table view selection method doesn't need to be implemented because the selection automatically triggers the segue. If you follow the guide in detail and to the end you will configure the segue and the handling of the segue trigger to configure the new detail view before it appears on screen.