# Not able to Perform Row Selected Navigation On Custom UITableViewcell Xamarin.IOS

Tags: swift, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Navigation not been performed when using custom UITableViewCell Style on Selected Row Click:

```
Customcell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as Customcell 

if (cell == null)
    cell = new Customcell (cellIdentifier);

cell.UpdateCell(hotDogs[indexPath.Row].Name,
    hotDogs[indexPath.Row].Price.ToString(),
    UIImage.FromFile("Images/image1));

return cell;
```

But I am able to perform navigation when using UITableViewCell Default Style:

```
UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell;

if (cell == null)
{
    cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);
}
```

Row Selection Event Does not Even Trigger PrepareForSegueMethod when using custom UITableViewCell:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);
}
```

Comment: How do you Navigate through ur App?

Comment: i made a Segue in UI from UITableView to my navigated page

Comment: Sure, but how do you call  the Segue to perform an action and did you name that Segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Row Selection Event Does not Even Trigger PrepareForSegueMethod when using custom UITableViewCell

There are a lot of similar case like yours online.

Refer to [issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678356/custom-uitableviewcell-programatically-trigger-selection-segue),[issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915789/custom-uitableviewcell-not-calling-prepareforsegue),[issue3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236975/prepareforsegue-not-called-from-custom-uitableviewcell).

The best workaround: Remove the "selection segue" and create a push segue in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` programmatically.

```
override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    this.PerformSegue("segueId", this);
}
```

Then this will trigger `PrepareForSegue` method.